# Notesagent debugging

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm currently developping an agent unter HCL/IBM/Lotus Notes Domino.
A LotusScript agent is not an option, so I'm using a Java agent.
Running the agent from my Notes Database works fine.

However I cannot manage to get any debugging to work.
I`ve tried running the agent locally or on a server and I`ve tried setting up a JavaApplication Debugger (failed, as there is no Main class) and a Remote Debugger (set but does not connect to JVM). 
But when I run the agent no breakpoint is toggled.

Appart from this documentation:

which i followed step by step but cant get to work, I did not find any other ways to debug.

In short:
- Agent is running
- Debugging as a Java Application is no possible (no main method)
- Remote Debugging does not work (no connection to localhost even though the notes.ini is set up to allow debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Bob Balaban's old blog, to this [post](http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/programming-domino-with-java-final-flush) where he provided links to the sections of the book he wrote about Programming Notes 4.6 with Java. Don't worry about the fact that it's really old. Click on the link to the 4th section. Then click on the link the Chapter 9, which is about debugging Java agents. Like I said, it's old, but it's still good info.